# PHP - Having $_SESSION as an array and adding $_SESSION to array

Tags: php, session

Originally, I wanted to have a $_SESSION that is linked to a button that when clicked, adds +1 to the $_SESSION. I was able to that, but could not find a way to display all of the clicks. It would only display the amoutn of clicks in total, not individual clicks.

I tried making a $_SESSION into an array, and putting a $_SESSION into each click for the button. As stated above, I can display the amount of clicks before going to the main page, but cannot seem to put the numbers in an array.

```
 session_start();
        
// The array in which all the clicks would be stored
$_SESSION['Counter'] = array();

// This stores the amount of clicks before going to the main page. Cannot seem to be able to display each value individually        
$_SESSION['Counter_Value'];

// toggles on click of button
if(isset($_POST['SLRI_Btn'])) {

    // This will display the amount of clicks per page. I do not know how to manipulate this data piece
    $_SESSION['Counter_Value']++;

     // Adds to array
    array_push($_SESSION['Counter'], $_SESSION['Counter_Value']);
}


// ON MAIN PAGE

// This prints out main array. Currently is empty anytime anything is added
print_r($_SESSION['Counter']);

// Prints out the number of clicks. Works perfectly
echo $_SESSION['Counter_Value'];
```

Comment: You don't initialize `$_SESSION['Counter_Value']` in your code snippet. Try `$_SESSION['Counter_Value'] = 0;` to store an initial integer in there.

Comment: That would normally work, but when the page refreshes, the value of $_SESSION defaults back to what it was declared as.

Comment: The only way I was able to make the value of $_SESSION['Counter_Value] auto increment was to just initialize it and add 1 to it every time a button is clicked. That way when the page refreshes the value stays added

Comment: In that case, check for `$_SESSION['Counter_Value']`'s existence first: `if ( empty( $_SESSION['Counter_Value'] ) ) { $_SESSION['Counter_Value'] = 0; }`

Comment: Assuming you fixed this by reading the comments, if you're adding 1 each time, are you printing `1,2,3,4,5,6` for 6 clicks? just store the integer and `print_r(range(1,$_SESSION['Counter_Value']));`